# Why does my webscraper return [] to powershell?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

My webscraper using python, BeautifulSoup, and Selenium returns "[]" . Originally I was just using BeautifulSoup and had the same issue, and since what i'm trying to scrape is weather data I tried using selenium.
Here is the code and html snippet, I'm really new to this so thank you in advance:)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://wx.ikitesurf.com/spot/93670")

time.sleep(5)

windspeed = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jw-spot-list-marker")

print (windspeed)
  
driver.close()
```

html

```
<span class="jw-list-view-wind-desc">9 (g15) mph W</span>
```

Comment: I don't understand, the class you are referencing in your code and your HTML are not the same. They are not part of the website either at least on my firefox.

Comment: Please take a look at your code and determine what you're trying to find.  if you're trying to find ```jw-list-view-wind-desc``` but you have ```driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jw-spot-list-marker")```, you're not going to find it.